# How to specify the position of parsed XHTML using itextsharp

Tags: xhtml, itext

I use itextsharp for creating a pdf. I need to place XHTML on it so I uase the XMLWorkerHelper class:

```
iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper worker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
worker.ParseXHtml(pdfWrite, doc, new StringReader(sb.ToString()));
```

However I would like to specify a position for the parsed XHTML. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**

I thought I will post the code in the case someone else runs into this. The link provided below was for JAVA and in C# things work a bit different.

First you need a class for gathering the Elements:

```
class ElementHandlerClass : iTextSharp.tool.xml.IElementHandler
{
    public List<IElement> elements = new List<IElement>();

    public void Add(iTextSharp.tool.xml.IWritable input)
    {
        if (input is iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.WritableElement)
        {
            elements.AddRange(((iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.WritableElement)input).Elements());
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use it

```
 ElementHandlerClass ehc = new ElementHandlerClass();
 worker.ParseXHtml(ehc, new StringReader(sb.ToString()));
```

Now you have the elements. Next step is to create a ColumnText and fill it with the Elements:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText ct = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText(pdfWrite.DirectContent);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(200, 300, 300, 500);
foreach (IElement element in ehc.elements)
     ct.AddElement(element);
ct.Go();
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the syntax in C#. This will certainly help for further reference. I always have difficulties translating my answers from Java to C#, so it helps when somebody provides feedback on my Java answers in the form of working C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the answers of two previous questions on StackOverflow.

The first answer you need, is the one to [How to get particular html table contents to write it in pdf using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530852/how-to-get-particular-html-table-contents-to-write-it-in-pdf-using-itext)

In this answer, you learn how to parse an XHTML source into a list of `Element` objects.

Once you have this list, you need the answer to [itext ColumnText ignores alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142623/itext-columntext-ignores-alignment)

You can create a `ColumnText` object, define a rectangle with the `setSimpleColumn()` method, add all the elements retrieved from the XHTML using XML Worker with the `addElement()` method, and `go()` to add that content.