# iText(Sharp) - Text is different when drawn with cell event vs. directly

Tags: itext

I've got a PdfPTable in which I am drawing simple text:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font f2 = new Font(bf, 10.0f);
PdfPTable tab = new PdfPTable(2);
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dude", f2)));
```

And that's all fine and dandy.  But then in order to do some [fancier stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748444/itextsharp-tables-with-headers-and-subheaders), I'm trying to get cell events to work:

```
Font f2 = new Font(bf, 10.0f);   // Pretend this is a global
class CellEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    void IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle r, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvases[0]);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(r);
        ct.AddElement(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dude", f2)));
        ct.Go();
    }
}
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
PdfPTable tab = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell ce = new PdfPCell();
ce.CellEvent = new CellEvent();
table.AddCell(ce);
```

When I do this though, the cell is drawn quite differently.  My actual text is multiple lines long, and when drawn directly (adding the phrase directly to the cell) the text lines are quite close together vertically; when drawn via the cell event, there is a lot of space between the text lines and it doesn't fit in the box the PdfPTable provides for me.

Is there a different, more preferred method for drawing text inside IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout()?  Or are there just some formatting parameters I need to copy from PdfPCell into ColumnText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something very wrong with this snippet:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvases[0]);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(r);
ct.AddElement(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dude", f2)));
ct.Go();
```

More specifically:

```
ct.AddElement(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dude", f2)));
```

You can not use the `PdfPCell` object outside of the context of a `PdfPTable`.

As for the differences between content in `PdfPCell` and `ColumnText`, you may want to read the answers to these questions:

- [itext ColumnText ignores alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142623/itext-columntext-ignores-alignment)
- [Right aligning text in PdfPCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607970/right-aligning-text-in-pdfpcell)

The content of a `PdfPCell` is actually stored in a `ColumnText` object, but a `PdfPCell` may have a padding.

There's also **text mode** versus **composite mode**. You are talking about the distance between two lines. In **text mode**, this distance is defined at the level of the `PdfPCell`/`ColumnText` using the `setLeading()` method. In **composite mode**, this parameter is ignored. Instead, the leading of the elements added to the `PdfPCell`/`ColumnText` is used.

For instance: if `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are three `Paragraph` objects, each having a different *leading*, then `ct` will have text with three different leadings if you do this:

```
ct.addElement(p1);
ct.addElement(p2);
ct.addElement(p3);
```

Comment: You are quite correct about my snippet being terribly wrong, that's not actually how my code is, I just screwed it up while copying it into stack overflow.  It does in fact just say ct.AddElement(new Phrase("Dude", f2)).

Comment: In that case, the default *leading* of the `Phrase` is used. That's 1.5 times the font size of `f2`. As that font size is 10, the leading is 15.

Comment: Bingo!  In my IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout, I just set the phrase's Leading equal to the phrase's font size and it's beautiful now.